# How to fill/shade space between timelines, plotted with ggplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, fill

I have a 12x13 matrix that looks like that:

```
monat   beob    werex_00    werex_11    werex_22    werex_33    werex_44    werex_55    werex_66    werex_77    werex_88    werex_99    Min Max
1   22.4930171  9.1418697   8.1558828   8.0312839   10.013298   8.8922567   9.395811    10.7933080  6.5136136   8.721697    10.279974   0.108381    59.65309
2   25.1414834  13.5886794  9.1694683   10.8709352  13.021066   10.3316655  10.579970   17.0555902  7.5915886   11.035921   13.366310   0.924013    66.94970
3   33.8286673  16.3800292  10.0202342  11.3072626  17.674761   16.1370288  15.018551   15.3331395  12.6856599  15.479521   13.929905   -0.794309   78.78572
4   22.0579421  11.9930633  8.4899130   8.2304118   12.987301   7.8763578   8.554007    12.4956321  9.4723508   7.057423    7.688662    -10.496481  49.01380
5   2.5535161   -2.4503375  -4.2354520  -3.6309377  -2.969866   -4.5876993  -5.383716   -3.2612018  -5.2054387  -2.780719   -4.359513   -19.579135  32.54282
6   -2.4405826  -8.8534136  -9.4666674  -7.4249244  -7.820072   -9.1485440  -8.546798   -7.8179739  -7.4222923  -10.978398   -12.644807 -22.821617  18.62139
7   -2.2580848  -6.7569968  -8.3390114  -8.8757506  -8.248305   -8.4171552  -7.760800   -5.7471163  -8.7864075  -6.239596   -8.870658   -22.933219  20.84375
8   -0.3448858  -5.6683742  -5.0467756  -5.7201820  -2.800106   -5.9640095  -5.011171   -3.3557601  -2.8967683  -4.407761   -6.146411   -17.042893  17.86556
9   3.3963303   0.4305926   -0.8554308  -0.9985536  -1.184610   -0.5520555  0.347758    -0.3838614  -0.2199835  -1.174712   -1.630363   -8.533647   19.66163
10  5.1839209   1.6050281   1.1578316   1.8503193   2.327975    1.6633771   1.557532    1.5563157   2.2776155   1.667714    1.333829    -4.686715   31.17342
11  9.2551418   4.4810518   2.9992301   4.9848408   3.824927    4.2413024   3.939119    5.4256008   3.5804488   4.965302    3.790589    -1.615777   43.90991
12  18.2233848  7.7648233   6.3344735   7.3477135   6.573620    7.1884950   7.428654    7.3119002   6.9405167   7.663072    8.342437    0.014096    62.83760
```

That are time-lines of a certain value. In the next step I plot it with `ggplot()`. Therefore I used the `melt()` operation to get the matrix in shape for plot:

```
R1_Grundwasserneubildung_Rg1Rg2_Monat_mean_druckreif <- melt(R1_Grundwasserneubildung_Rg1Rg2_Monat_mean, na.rm = FALSE, id.vars="monat")
```

This data looks like that now:

```
    Monat   Projektion  value
1   1   beob    22.4930171
2   2   beob    25.1414834
3   3   beob    33.8286673
4   4   beob    22.0579421
5   5   beob    2.5535161
6   6   beob    -2.4405826
7   7   beob    -2.2580848
8   8   beob    -0.3448858
9   9   beob    3.3963303
10  10  beob    5.1839209
11  11  beob    9.2551418
12  12  beob    18.2233848
13  1   werex_00    9.1418697
14  2   werex_00    13.5886794
15  3   werex_00    16.3800292
16  4   werex_00    11.9930633
17  5   werex_00    -2.4503375
18  6   werex_00    -8.8534136
19  7   werex_00    -6.7569968
20  8   werex_00    -5.6683742
21  9   werex_00    0.4305926
22  10  werex_00    1.6050281
23  11  werex_00    4.4810518
24  12  werex_00    7.7648233
25  1   werex_11    8.1558828
... ... ... ...
```

I also added some new names for the melted data (as already seen above):

```
names(R1_Grundwasserneubildung_Rg1Rg2_Monat_mean_druckreif)<-c("Monat","Projektion","value")
```

Next step defines some custom colors for the plot:

```
Projektionen_Farben<-c("#000000","#00EEEE","#EEAD0E","#006400","#BDB76B","#EE7600","#68228B","#8B0000","#1E90FF","#EE6363","#556B2F","#D6D6D6","#D6D6D6")
```

Now I plot the melted data:

```
ggplot(R1_Grundwasserneubildung_Rg1Rg2_Monat_mean_druckreif,
       aes(x=Monat,y=value,color=Projektion,group=Projektion)) + 
       geom_line(size=0.8) + 
       xlab("Monat") +
       ylab("Grundwasserneubildung [mm/Monat]") +
       ggtitle("Grundwasserneubildung") +
       theme_bw() +
       scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
                          labels = c("Jan","Feb","Mär","Apr","Mai","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Okt","Nov","Dez")) +
       theme(axis.title=element_text(size=15,vjust = 0.3, face="bold"),
             title=element_text(size=15,vjust = 1.5,face="bold")) +
       scale_colour_manual(values = Projektionen_Farben)
```

Sorry, but I haven't got enough reputation to post a pic of the plot. 
Now I want to fill/shade the space between the Max-line and the Min-line with, lets say, a light grey (alpha=.3). I have tried with `geom_ribbon()` but haven't found the right way to define `x`, `ymin` and `ymax` as needed. Does someone know a way to fill the space between these two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your original data frame for the `geom_ribbon()` and provide columns `Min` and `Max` as `ymin` and `ymax`.

```
  + geom_ribbon(data=R1_Grundwasserneubildung_Rg1Rg2_Monat_mean,
                  aes(x=monat,ymin=Min,ymax=Max),
                   inherit.aes=FALSE,alpha=0.3,color="grey30")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Thats funny, i tried nearly the same, also with the orig. data, but there was always some warning. As always the devil lies in the detail. Thanks

Comment: I assume the problem was missing inherit.aes=FALSE argument - that ensures that geom_ribbon() does look for the same variables as in ggplot().