# Shade region between two lines with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill

I produce the folowing two lines with ggplot and would like to shade a specific region between the two lines i.e. where y=x² is greater than y=2x, where 2 <= x <= 3.

```
# create data #

x<-as.data.frame(c(1,2,3,4))
colnames(x)<-"x"
x$twox<-2*x$x
x$x2<-x$x^2

# Set colours #

blue<-rgb(0.8, 0.8, 1, alpha=0.25)
clear<-rgb(1, 0, 0, alpha=0.0001)

# Define region to fill #

x$fill <- "no fill"
x$fill[(x$x2 > x$twox) & (x$x <= 3 & x$x >= 2)] <- "fill"

# Plot #

ggplot(x, aes(x=x, y=twox)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = twox)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = x2)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill=fill)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits=c(0,20)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits=c(0,5)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(clear,blue))
```

The result is the following which just shades the region under the line y=2x, and this no matter what the x-value - why?

[image]

Comment: http://www.r-bloggers.com/shading-between-two-lines-ggplot/

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20260749/903061

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135962/how-to-fill-with-different-colors-between-two-lines-originally-fill-geom-poly

Answer (score 48, accepted):

How about using `geom_ribbon` instead

```
ggplot(x, aes(x=x, y=twox)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = twox)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = x2)) +
    geom_ribbon(data=subset(x, 2 <= x & x <= 3), 
          aes(ymin=twox,ymax=x2), fill="blue", alpha=0.5) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits=c(0,20)) +
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits=c(0,5)) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values=c(clear,blue))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Does geom_ribbon always work for this kind of task? http://www.r-bloggers.com/shading-between-two-lines-ggplot/ states it does not.

Comment: There is a problem if you don't have the point of intersection in your data.frame. Example: 
x <- seq(0,5,by=0.2); df <- data.frame(x = x, l1 = 5-x, l2 = x); library(ggplot2); ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) + geom_line(aes(y=l1)) + geom_line(aes(y=l2)) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = pmin(l1,l2), ymax = pmax(l1,l2)), fill = "blue", alpha=0.5);

Comment: Thanks for that illustration!

Answer (score 5):

I think that geom_ribbon is the way to go. There are 2 steps to go:

1. Data Manipulation: You should manipulate data to define ymin & ymax for arguments in geom_ribbon
2. Draw plot with geom_ribbon.

Let's see my example:

```
#Data 
library(gcookbook) 
# Data Manipulation
cb <-subset(climate,Source=="Berkeley")
cb$valence[cb$Anomaly10y >= 0.3] <- "pos"
cb$valence[cb$Anomaly10y < 0.3]  <- "neg"
cb$min <- ifelse(cb$Anomaly10y >= 0.3, 0.3, cb$Anomaly10y)
cb$max <- ifelse(cb$Anomaly10y >= 0.3, cb$Anomaly10y, 0.3)

#Drawing plot
ggplot(cb,aes(x=Year,y=Anomaly10y)) +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = min, ymax = max, fill = valence), alpha = 0.75) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "orange")) +
geom_line(aes(col = valence), size = 1) +
scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "orange")) +
geom_hline(yintercept=0.3, col = "blue") +
theme_bw()
```