# Shade area between lines with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to shade the area between the grouped lines. I've tried different approaches but I don't manage to do it.

```
df <- data.frame(year = rep(c(1950:1955), each = 2),
                 gender = factor(rep(c("male", "female"), times = 6)),
                 value = c(40526812, 37450509, 43027405,
                            40135682, 45801088, 43130369,
                            48579427, 46077640, 50948574,
                            48493786, 53052094, 50537984))

df |> 
  ggplot(aes(year, value, group = gender)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shade region between two lines with ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586635/shade-region-between-two-lines-with-ggplot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define the boundaries of the area by using a `pivot_wider` to create the `ymax` and `ymin` of the area in `geom_ribbon` so you don't need to subset per argument. So it will be easier to reproduce. Here an example:

```r
df <- data.frame(year = rep(c(1950:1955), each = 2),
                 gender = factor(rep(c("male", "female"), times = 6)),
                 value = c(40526812, 37450509, 43027405,
                           40135682, 45801088, 43130369,
                           48579427, 46077640, 50948574,
                           48493786, 53052094, 50537984))

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
area <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = gender, values_from = value) %>%
  mutate(
    ymax = pmax(male, female),
    ymin = pmin(male, female)
  )

ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(year, y = value, group = gender)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(data = area, mapping = aes(year, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha = 0.4, inherit.aes = FALSE )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I find this solution brilliant. Thanks!!

Comment: What does inherit.aes does? I've never used it.

Comment: When inherit.aes if FALSE, it overrides the default aesthetics instead of combining them. This is useful because we use in this case two dataframes so we can define both the data and aesthetics so that is does not inherit the behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `geom_ribon` which allows to shade areas within axis values.
A stronger alpha will play on the shader intensity.

```
  ggplot(data=df, aes(year, value, group = gender)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_ribbon(data=subset(df, 1950 <= year & year <= 1955), 
              aes(ymin=rep(subset(df, gender=='female')$value, each=2), 
                  ymax=rep(subset(df, gender=='male')$value, each=2)), fill="blue", alpha=0.5)
```

[image]